Instagram API - Sorry the content isn't available right now?
I am using Instagram API with Instagram Login

I am using instagram business login in which I want permission such as manange_message, manage_comments and business_basic
After getting code I exchange it for short live token.
Issue
When I am exchanging short live token for long live token through


    curl -i -X GET https://graph.instagram.com/access_token \
        -F grant_type=ig_exchange_token \
        -F client_secret={{client_secret}} \
        -F access_token={{access_token}}


I am getting Sorry this content isn't available right now
This is also I am getting 400 Bad Request
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token"
I ensure you that short live token is valid as I have checked in meta debugger
I also tried to make API call using short live token and still getting Sorry this content isn't available right now.
I am expecting longlive token in response

Can't tell what actual request you are making, when you just copy&paste from the documentation. An often made mistake is to not properly replace the "placeholders" in there, and leaving the curly braces in.
